# How to store value from a IQueryable list to a string variable?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

Hi my code is as below:

```
 List<COSIS_DAL.PaymentsHeader> pheadr = c.GetPaymentHeaderByPayDate(PayDate);

 public List<PaymentsHeader> GetPaymentHeaderByPayDate(DateTime payDate)
    {
        CosisEntities db = new CosisEntities();

        IQueryable<PaymentsHeader> query = (from p in db.PaymentsHeaders
                    where p.PaymentDate.Value.Day == payDate.Day
                    && p.PaymentDate.Value.Month == payDate.Month
                    && p.PaymentDate.Value.Year == payDate.Year
                    select p);

        return query.ToList();

    }
```

so I want to save the data from pheadr to a string like this:

```
     string keyword = Convert.ToString(pheadr.Select(m => m.VoucherNumber));
```

but I am not getting the value inside the list. Instead of the value I am getting this:

```
      System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[COSIS_DAL.PaymentsHeader,System.String]
```

Please help me on this. I am really in trouble for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
string keyword ;
if(pheader != null)
   keyword = pheader.FirstOrDefault().VoucherNumber;
else
   keyword = "";
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `FirstOrDefault()` if you access a property immediately afterwards without checking for `null`?

Comment: @Ajay not it looks good :) try to use `@` so users are notified ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `pheadr.Select(m => m.VoucherNumber)` isn't a *single* value... It's a *collection* of values... You could try:

```
string keyword = string.Join(", ", pheadr.Select(m => Convert.ToString(m.VoucherNumber)));
```

if you really want multiple voucher numbers separated by a `,`.

or you could put it in a separate collection:

```
List<string> vouchers = pheadr.Select(m => Convert.ToString(m.VoucherNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: There was also error with using `Convert.ToString` on `IEnumerable` :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your helping answer..as I am new n LINQ you really helped me a lot..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
var keywords = pheadr.Select(x=>x.VoucherNumber.ToString()).ToList();
```

It will select all voucher numbers to list of strings. Is it what you wanted? `keywords` is `List<string>`

The string you are getting is because you are converting Linq expression to string, not inner field.

For only first record, use:

```
var keyword = Convert.ToString(pheadr.First().VoucherNumber);
```

If you are not sure that it will always return one value try:

```
var ph = pheadr.FirstOrDefault();
var keyword = ph!=null?Convert.ToString(ph.VoucherNumber):"";
```

EDIT:
as @xanatos suggested I used `Convert` instead `ToString`

Comment: But note that there is a subtle difference between `.ToString()` and `Convert.ToString()`. The first one will explode badly with `null` values, the second one will simply return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..yes it is now selecting the voucher number as a string but I want it to be store into a string variable because it will always return only one voucher number. Can you please suggest me what I can do for this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `pheadr` is a collection of `PaymentsHeader` objects, the line

```
pheadr.Select(m => m.VoucherNumber)
```

will select each `PaymentsHeader` `VoucherNumber` property, which I'll assume is a string. So, the thing that will be returned will be a collection of strings. You can loop through it, you can cast it to a list or an array, or you can stick it in a stew, but you can't just call `.ToString` on it. That invokes the default `object.ToString` behaviour that just dumps the name of the class, which is what you got.

If you want to extract, for example, a comma-separated list of those strings, you can use:

```
string.Join(",", pheadr.Select(m => m.VoucherNumber))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your detail explanation...really helped me to know more about LINQ...